# i get this error when I am running my hangman game in python: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I start the program nothing appears to be wrong. It's only when I close the program that I get the error message:

> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

when I run my program my buttons also have no affect. I commented the line of code that is giving me the error. Sorry the code is so long but the error is in the draw_letters() function. I have no idea what this error could be.

Edit: putting mainwindow.mainloop() at the end of the program doesn't help, it just gives me a different error. This is because my program needs to wait for user input before updating the canvas.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

# I'm using this import to create a command with a parameter for my buttons
from functools import partial


class EventListener(object):
    def __init__(self, current_letter):
        self.current_letter = current_letter

    def key_input(self, char):
        self.current_letter = char

    def get_current_letter(self):
        return self.current_letter


def get_random_word():
    word_list = []
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as word_file:
        for word in word_file:
            if 4 < len(word) < 14:
                word_list.append(word.strip('\n'))

    return word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list) - 1)]


def draw_gallows():
    canvas.create_line(60, 350, 300, 350, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 350, 105, 20, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 20, 240, 20, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(240, 20, 240, 50, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 85, 170, 20, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 95, 180, 20, width=2)


def draw_body_part(mistakes):
    if mistakes <= 1:
        canvas.create_oval(209, 50, 269, 110, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 2:
        canvas.create_line(240, 110, 240, 260, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 3:
        canvas.create_line(240, 180, 190, 120, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 4:
        canvas.create_line(240, 180, 290, 120, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 5:
        canvas.create_line(240, 260, 200, 330, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 6:
        canvas.create_line(240, 260, 280, 330, width=2)


def draw_dashes(word, x):
    for i in word:
        canvas.create_line(x, 260, x + 25, 260)
        x += 36


def draw_letters(letters, x):
    for letter in letters:
        canvas.create_text(x, 260, letter)  # this is the line that is erring #####################
        x += 36


# TODO: Set up end condition window
def end_condition(hasWon):
    pass


def play_one_round():
    word = get_random_word()
    print(word)
    correct_guesses = []
    mistakes = 0

    x = (700 // len(word)) + 260
    draw_dashes(word, x)

    main_window.mainloop()

    while (len(correct_guesses) != len(word)) or (mistakes == 6):

        guess = button_clicked.current_letter
        print(guess)
        if guess in word:
            correct_guesses.append(guess)
            draw_letters(correct_guesses, x)
        elif guess not in word:
            mistakes += 1
            draw_body_part(mistakes)

    if mistakes == 6:
        end_condition(hasWon=False)
    else:
        end_condition(hasWon=True)


# creating the window, canvas and buttons
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Hangman')
main_window.geometry('800x580+240+30')
main_window.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(main_window, background='white', width=800, height=360)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

keyboard_panel = tk.Frame(main_window)
keyboard_panel.grid(row=1, column=0)

helv17 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=17, weight='bold')
helv12 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12)

button_clicked = EventListener('')

for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
    if i < ord('j'):
        column = ord('a')
        row = 0
    elif i < ord('s'):
        column = ord('j')
        row = 1
    else:
        column = ord('s')
        row = 2

    # the partial keyword allows you to have a command with a parameter
    button = tk.Button(keyboard_panel, text=chr(i), font=helv17,
                       command=partial(button_clicked.key_input, chr(i)), width=4)
    button.grid(row=row, column=i - column, padx=10, pady=10)

new_game_button = tk.Button(keyboard_panel, text='New Game', font=helv12)
new_game_button.grid(row=2, column=8)

draw_gallows()

play_one_round()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. The problem is that the play one round is going through a while loop even though it shouldn't. To fix my issue I had to completely remove the play_one_round function and put all the logic in that function into the key_input function (same as the button command), I also had to remove the while loop. After changing that, it made sense to put the mainloop at the end of the program. I've now finished the program with no errors. The only thing I would change now is the end_condition window. If anyone has a similar error, I hope you learn from my struggles. For those who want a free hangman game, enjoy.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
# Import to create a command with a parameter for buttons
from functools import partial


def get_random_word():
    word_list = []
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as word_file:
        for txt_word in word_file:
            if 4 < len(txt_word) < 14:
                word_list.append(txt_word.strip('\n'))

    return word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list) - 1)]


def draw_gallows():
    canvas.create_line(60, 350, 300, 350, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 350, 105, 20, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 20, 240, 20, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(240, 20, 240, 50, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 85, 170, 20, width=2)
    canvas.create_line(105, 95, 180, 20, width=2)


def draw_body_part(mistakes):
    if mistakes <= 1:
        canvas.create_oval(209, 50, 269, 110, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 2:
        canvas.create_line(240, 110, 240, 260, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 3:
        canvas.create_line(240, 180, 190, 120, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 4:
        canvas.create_line(240, 180, 290, 120, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 5:
        canvas.create_line(240, 260, 200, 330, width=2)
    elif mistakes <= 6:
        canvas.create_line(240, 260, 280, 330, width=2)


def draw_dashes(word, x):
    for i in word:
        canvas.create_line(x, 260, x + 25, 260)
        x += 36


def draw_letters(word, letter, x):
    helv20 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
    for l in word:
        if letter == l:
            canvas.create_text(x + 10, 249, text=letter, font=helv20)
        x += 36


def end_condition(has_won):

    def new_game_button_command():
        end_window.destroy()
        new_game()

    end_window = tk.Tk()
    end_window.geometry('250x180+400+200')
    end_window.title('Game Over!')
    end_message_frame = tk.Frame(end_window)
    end_message_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    end_button_frame = tk.Frame(end_window)
    end_button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

    new_game_button = tk.Button(end_button_frame, text='Play new game',
                                command=new_game_button_command)
    new_game_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

    if has_won:
        end_message = tk.Label(end_message_frame, text='Congratulations!! You won!!!', )
    else:
        end_message = tk.Label(end_message_frame, text=f'You Lost! The word was "{word}"')
    end_message.pack()

    end_window.mainloop()


def new_game():
    global word
    global correct_guesses
    global mistakes
    global x
    global total_guesses
    global canvas

    canvas.destroy()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(main_window, background='white', width=800, height=360)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    draw_gallows()
    word = get_random_word()
    correct_guesses = []
    mistakes = 0
    total_guesses = []

    x = (700 // len(word)) + 260
    draw_dashes(word, x)


def key_input(char):
    global word
    global correct_guesses
    global mistakes
    global x
    global total_guesses

    guess = char

    if guess not in total_guesses:
        for letter in word:
            if guess == letter:
                correct_guesses.append(guess)
                draw_letters(word, guess, x)
        if guess not in word:
            mistakes += 1
            draw_body_part(mistakes)
    total_guesses.append(guess)

    if mistakes == 6:
        end_condition(has_won=False)
    elif len(correct_guesses) == len(word):
        end_condition(has_won=True)


# creating the window, canvas and buttons
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title('Hangman')
main_window.geometry('800x580+240+30')
main_window.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(main_window, background='white', width=800, height=360)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)


keyboard_panel = tk.Frame(main_window)
keyboard_panel.grid(row=1, column=0)

helv17 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=17, weight='bold')
helv12 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12)


for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
    if i < ord('j'):
        column = ord('a')
        row = 0
    elif i < ord('s'):
        column = ord('j')
        row = 1
    else:
        column = ord('s')
        row = 2

    # the partial keyword allows you to have a command with a parameter
    button = tk.Button(keyboard_panel, text=chr(i), font=helv17,
                       command=partial(key_input, chr(i)), width=4)
    button.grid(row=row, column=i - column, padx=10, pady=10)

reset_button = tk.Button(keyboard_panel, text='New Game', font=helv12, command=new_game)
reset_button.grid(row=2, column=8)

draw_gallows()

word = get_random_word()
correct_guesses = []
mistakes = 0
total_guesses = []

x = (700 // len(word)) + 260
draw_dashes(word, x)

main_window.mainloop()
```